# asp:LinkButton in Grid change link text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn >
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" CommandName="OpWin" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrgId").ToString() %>'></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Instead of it saying Enter Info, I like to dynamically change the text based on some conditions in my code behind.

I tried the following in my code behind in ItemCommand:

```
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        LinkButton lbutton = item["lnkBtn"].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        // Enter some condition here  to change button text dynamically          
         lbutton.Text = "test";

    }
```

Comment: what are you talking about where in your code are you even stating and or saying the following `Enter Info` also with such a high rep one would think that you would formulate a question better than what you have presented. also where is the code behind in regards to the `LinkButton` CommandName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Telerik personally, but most (template-based) .NET controls have an event like "ItemCreated" (or "RowCreated") where you could run the logic and change the text of the button by doing something like this:

```
private void OnItemCreated(object sender, ItemCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (e.Item.FindControl("LinkButtonName") as LinkButton);
    if(btn != null)
    {
        // Logic to determine button text.
        btn.Text = "Whatever";
    }
}
```